# string formatting not working as expected

Tags: python, formatting, maxlength

I am trying to format strings to print in a fashion that fits the following:

```
Payday           1000.00
groceries         -50.00
dinner out wit   -175.00
bacon, eggs, &    -50.00
total: 725
```

And for this I am using string formatting.
The column on the left ('description') cannot exceed a max length of 23 characters, and the column on the right ('amount') cannot exceed a max length of 7 characters.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
def __str__(self):
        balance = 0
        transactions = []
        nl = '\n'
        header = self.category.center(30, '*')
        for item in self.ledger:
            transaction = item['amount']
            balance += transaction
            item['amount'] = '{:.2f}'.format(item['amount'])
            description = '{:.<23}'.format(item['description'])
            amount = '{:.>7}'.format(item['amount'])
            transactions.append(f'{description}{amount}')
        total = f'Total: {balance}'
        return f"{header}\n{nl.join(tuple(transactions))}\n{total}"
```

With what I have above, everything works right for the most part, however none of my strings are being constrained by their max lengths and I cannot figure out why.

Below is what results whenever I run this code as is:

```
*************Food*************
Payday.................1000.00
groceries...............-50.00
dinner out with friends-175.00
bacon, eggs, vegetables, fruits and salad for breakfast.-50.00
Total: 725
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to truncate the columns at their max length, you can use string slicing before appending them:

```
description = description[:23]
amount = amount[:7]
transactions.append(f'{description}{amount}')
```

If the slice exceeds the length of the string, Python just returns the whole string, so this will work even when a string is shorter than your max length.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Can't believe it was something so simple. 
Thanks so much for the help!